# Ionic app needs to hit server not localhost to login and to test on device

Tags: php, ios, authentication, ionic-framework

I need to test my ionic app on a device and I can't log in.

I am using ionic view. http://view.ionic.io/

I can login with my app on the browser and on the emulator. 
I ran `ionic upload` and my app is now available to view on the app BUT I can't login. I get the alert messages I set up, "Invalid Credentials".

I think the reason is because my API call to login is to the local server.

`Route::get('/api/login/{username}/{password}', 'ApiV2Controller@login_user_or_admin');`

**and on the browser...**

`http://localhost/api/login/username/userpassword`

**and on my Ionic app this is what the $http get looks like..**

```
self.login = function(userLogin, userPw) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get("http://localhost/api/login" + "/" + userLogin + "/" + userPw)
    .success(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      if (!result.result) {
        deferred.resolve(false);
        return false;
      }
      UserService.save(result.data); 
      console.log("Login Credentials Submitted Succesfully!");
      deferred.resolve(true);
      return true;
    }).error(function(data) {
      alert('Something went wrong');
      deferred.resolve(data);
    })

  return deferred.promise;
}; //login()
```

I think that's the code in need of updates or what I need to reference so that someone can help me out.

How do I approach this issue? What gets fixed first? The route in the API from local host to the actual website address?

I would appreciate some pointers as to what I need to know or how to approach this issue and perhaps what needs to be added or refactored.

P.S. could this be related to my issue? http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: you pc's network and mobile's network same?

Comment: @PareshGami Thanks for reading over my issue. I am sorry but when you say "Network" what do you mean? exactly? 
(excuse my ignorance..)

Comment: i mean when you make build of your project and make apk and install in device right?? now you try to call web services with http://localhost, but device cannot know what is localhost. localhost means your pc's server so you need to make it live

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a request on your computer IP (can be get by typing  on linux).
Hitting on localhost will make a call on local of your mobile/testing device and not on the localhost server of your computer.

http.post(http://localIP-ofYourComputer)